# How does Extra attack interact with multi attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, barbarian

I've got a barbarian 5/druid 3 multi class in my game and I'm trying to figure out how extra attack and multi attack, say from being a bear, will stack. 3 attacks total? 4? The PHB bursts into flames and summons a dread elder ruleset?

Comment: Hey Brightstorm, Welcome to the site! Make sure to [take the tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get a chance.

Answer (score 5):

Wild shape says:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so.

Extra Attack says:

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of
>   once, whenever you take the **Attack action** on your turn.

Bears have an action alled Multiattack:

> ACTIONS
>
> Multiattack. The bear makes two attacks, one with its bite and
>   one with its claws.

So, you can either take two attacks using the Attack Action with the Extra Attack or you can use the Bear's Mutliattack action and attack twice.  You, however, can't do both because the types of actions are different.

Answer (score 4):

They don't stack. Extra Attack requires the Attack action. Multiattack is a different action.

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

Here's what the Monster Manual and DM's Basic Rules say about Multiattack:

> A creature that can make multiple attacks on its turn has the Multiattack action. A creature can't use Multiattack when making an opportunity attack, which must be a single melee attack.

Answer (score 1):

For wildshape, you retain all class features that can be used in a new shadow therefore you retain you're extra attack from barbarian, as well as the Unarmed defence bonus, because you aren't wearing armor.

However this does not mean you get 3 attacks, because extra attack gives you 1 extra attack, no more, and doesn't stack with other features that give an extra attack, "you cannot make more then two attacks with this feature unless this feature says you do" phb multiclassing.

It does not explicitly state that it does stack with multi-attack, but multi atrack is similar to thirsting blade in that it gives you the ability to have multiple attacks in one turn while not being the extra attack feature. In the phb we know that other abilities that give multiple attacks per turn (thirsting blade) do not stack with the extra attack feature.  therefore we can logically conclude that you can use the bear multi-attack option, (with the limitations listed)  or take an attack action and gain an extra attack from the level 5 barbarian extra attack ( and do 2 bites) but not both in the same round.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Needs a spellcheck and some prettying, but it is correct.

Comment: @András I didn't downvote, but while the conclusion is correct the reasoning is wrong.